# splitting column value in to three with two delimiter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have written an excel file with one column with values of:

```
col1
22125051|2/136|Possible Match
nan|3/4|Not Match
22125051|1/26|Match
```

these data are initially in different columns but I want to get the value of the said columns and put the data into one, and I did it by using .apply() and .join() then I added a delimiter | to separate the values

now I want to split the column per value then put it in to specific column in an existing .xlsx file.
say `df3 = pd.read_excel('type_primary_data.xlsx')`
and .columns[37], .columns[39], .columns[40]

### Desired ouput

```
svc_no       port      Result

22125051     2/136     Possible Match
nan          3/4       Not Match
22125051     1/26      Match
```

I am not sure what is the best way to do this in pandas.

## UPDATE

turns out that I need to match the adsl column to an existing .xlsx file
so, as the adsl matched with the said column I also wanted to get the svc_no and comparison result along with the matched adsl.

#### my ouput should be

```
adsl         svc_no       port      Result
3/4          nan          3/4       Not Match
1/26         22125051     1/26      Match
2/136        22125051     2/136     Possible Match
```

Comment: You will need a different library to manipulate excel files to this granularity (e.g. [`openpyxl`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)). Splitting `col1` is pretty simple, e.g.: `df[['svc_no', 'port', 'Result']] = df.col1.str.split('|', expand=True)`. Then you can drop `col1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the df.str.split method:

```
df =df[col1].str.split('|', expand=True)
```

Then, rename the comlumns since they will be numbers with:

```
df.rename(columns={'oldname':'newname'}
```

Try that. I cant comment because of reputation but I think that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

I'm a fan of using `extract` with naming within `regex` pattern

```
pat = '(?P<svc_no>.*)\|(?P<port>.*)\|(?P<Result>.*)'
df.col1.str.extract(pat, expand=True)

     svc_no   port          Result
0  22125051  2/136  Possible Match
1       nan    3/4       Not Match
2  22125051   1/26           Match
```

---

### Option 2

```
cols = dict(enumerate('svc_no port Result'.split()))
df.col1.str.extractall('([^|]+)')[0].unstack().rename(columns=cols)

match    svc_no   port          Result
0      22125051  2/136  Possible Match
1           nan    3/4       Not Match
2      22125051   1/26           Match
```